# Проблема динамического подсчета после создания новой строчки в таблице

Tags: html, jquery

Нарисовалась одна очень не приятная проблема, хочу создать таблицу с динамическим подсчетом и добавлением новых строчек, но после добавления строки, подсчет не производится.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Редактировать данные в таблице</title>

  <style>
    table {
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    th,
    td:first-child {
      background: #AFCDE7;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
      border-color: white;
    }
    
    td {
      background: #D8E6F3;
    }
    
    th:first-child,
    td:first-child {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    button {
      background: #AFCDE7;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <br><br><br>
  <table id="example1" contenteditable="true">
    <table id="example">
      <tr>
        <th>Номер</th>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>Цена</th>
        <th>Количество</th>
        <th>Сумма</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="number">1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">Название</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="count">2</td>
        <td class="sum">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="number">2</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">Название</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="count">2</td>
        <td class="sum">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="number">3</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">Название</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="count">2</td>
        <td class="sum">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="stockadd">Добавить строку</button>
  <script>
    $(".price,.count").on("input", function() {
      var $elements = $(this).siblings().addBack();
      var $price = $elements.filter(".price");
      var $count = $elements.filter(".count");
      var $sum = $elements.filter(".sum");
      $sum.text($price.text() * $count.text());

    });
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#stockadd").click(function() {
        var x = $(".number").text();
        var z = x.slice(-1);
        z++;
        $('#example').append('<tr> <td contenteditable="true" class="number">' + z + '</td> <td contenteditable="true">Название</td> <td contenteditable="true" class="price">0</td>  <td contenteditable="true" class="count">2</td> <td class="sum">0</td> </tr>');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: практически каждый день кто-то задает один и тот же вопрос. `$("#example1").on('input', ".price, .count", function(){ ....})`

Comment: @teran видимо пора сделать канонический вопрос-ответ и закрывать дублем  ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да странно что его до сих пор нет, ибо реально не далее чем вчера писал такой же коммент, при этом я не очень часто читаю по тэгу jquery

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ладно если это дубликат не могли бы выкинутся в меня ссылкой, если не сложно заранее спасибо))

Comment: @StarLord я не знаю есть ли он. поэтому и предложил его сделать в конце концов) щас бота спрошу