# Не работает подсветка строки таблицы, после динамического создания через AJAX?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      books_id = [];
      titles = [];
      $(data).each(function(index, value) {
        // if(value.completed)
        titles[index] = "<td>" + JSON.stringify(value.title) + "</td>";
        books_id[index] = "<td>" + JSON.stringify(value.id) + "</td>";
        $("#waypointsTable").append("<tr>" + titles[index] + books_id[index] + "</tr>");
      });
    }
  });

  $('#waypointsTable tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table style="width:50%" id="waypointsTable">
    <caption><b>Sort from JSON to table with jQuery</b></caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Простите....*** Почему подсветка строки не работает в таблице после динамичнного "заполнения таблицы" через ajax?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать плагины jquery с динамическим контентом или почему после AJAX отваливается javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625993/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-jquery-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-ajax-%d0%be)

Comment: Ну и ответ.... можно читать до утра :)

Comment: Зато в нем описано почему, зачем и как :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732606/

Comment: Сдесь лучше объяснение! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй css

```
tr:hover { background-color:yellow; }
```

Если все таки через jq

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      books_id = [];
      titles = [];
      $(data).each(function(index, value) {
        // if(value.completed)
        titles[index] = "<td>" + JSON.stringify(value.title) + "</td>";
        books_id[index] = "<td>" + JSON.stringify(value.id) + "</td>";
        $("#waypointsTable").append("<tr>" + titles[index] + books_id[index] + "</tr>");
      });
    }


  });
  
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
}, "#waypointsTable tr");

})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <table style="width:50%" id="waypointsTable">
    <caption><b>Sort from JSON to table with jQuery</b></caption>

    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Так намного проще! Спасибо!